# Using a Processing Library in Eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, processing

I am trying to use a MySQL library in Eclipse. I have imported the jar file and added the source location and it looks ok, I don't get any error messages in the editor. The problem is I get an error when I run the code. I can run the same code in Processing with no problem so I think something is wrong with how I imported the library. I have managed to use the Processing library in Eclipse so I thought there'd be no problem.

This is the error I get:

[image]

It says NoSuchMethodError for line 26. I've checked the methods involved in the MySQL constructor and I can see them and open them in the package explorer, it doesn't look like anything is missing.

I'm using BezierSQLib and I downloaded it from Github here: https://github.com/fjenett/sql-library-processing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think something is wrong with how I imported the library.

I doubt this is the problem.

The error is telling you that the SQL Library is looking for a function called `registerDispose()` in Processing, but your version of Processing doesn't have it.

The `registerDispose()` function was deprecated in Processing 2 and removed in Processing 3, so it's not surprising that the library can't find it.

So it looks like you're using an old version of the library, since the GitHub page says it supports Processing 3. I'd try making sure you're using the latest versions of both the library and Processing.

Comment: Thanks very much for your feedback. Turns out I was indeed using an older version of BezierSQL, found an updated version in the issues section of the Github and that's solved it. Really appreciate the help.